# $\int \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}$

Tags: integration

$\displaystyle\int \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}$

try to do $\displaystyle\int \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}=\displaystyle\int \frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}dt}{(t^4-1)}$ and try $t^2=\sin(u)$, etc. but didnt end up well.

I tried to use $tan(t/2)=x$ transformation and partial fraction decomposition in a irrational way but didnot do well.

Comment: hint put $t^2+1=\frac{1}{u}$

Comment: Use $t=\frac{1}{x}$ You will get $\frac{linear}{quadratic\sqrt{quadratic'}}$ Now substitute $quadratic'=u^2$

Comment: HERE COME @DatBoi!!!

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I'm not quite sure what you meant by that

Comment: @DatBoi the old meme, with the frog?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Damn! You got me! It was so random I couldn't relate.

Answer (score 3):

Try substituting $t=\sec{x}$:
\begin{align*}
&=\int \frac{ \sec{x} \tan{x}}{(\sec^2{x}+1)\tan{x}} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int \frac{ \cos{x} }{1+\cos^2{x}} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int \frac{ \mathrm{d}\left(\sin{x}\right) }{2-\sin^2{x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \text{artanh}\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \text{artanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{t\sqrt{2}}\right)+C\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Let $x= 1-\frac1{t^2}$. Then
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}
&= \frac12 \int\frac{dx}{(2-x)\sqrt x}= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{d\sqrt{\frac x2}}{1-\frac x2}\\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2}\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac x2}}{1-\sqrt{\frac x2}} +C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=\frac{1}{t}$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\int \frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right) \sqrt{1-x^2}} d x \\
& =-\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} d\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \\
& =\int \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2-2} d\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\\& = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{2}}\right|+C\\& = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}-\sqrt{2} t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}+\sqrt{2} t}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$